# Should I make all member variables the user inputs as attributes?

Tags: python, class, attributes

Let's say I have a class:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Should name and age be attributes that I convey in the documentation that the user of the class can access? The reason being that sometimes the instances are auto generated and maybe the user of the class wants to see what name was set to.

Comment: If the argument has to be assigned as a "mandatory" argument in order to invoke an instance of that class, then yes, it definitely should be conveyed in the documentation. Ultimately, it would be good to follow typical docstring behaviour in explaining how to interact with this class.

Comment: @idjaw yes, i document all arguments. I was wondering whether or not all the __init__ arguments should be made attributes the user can then access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a documentation for a `class`, you should always list and explain the parameters that are passed in. In an object such as this one, passing in the `name` and `age` are essential in order for the object to form, so it must be documented.

However, the following act of storing them as object attributes is a little more of a grey area regarding what to document. If I make an object as so:

```
person = MyClass("Miguelito", 75)
```

You know by your code that you can get the name and age as so:

```
print(person.name) #Prints "Miguelito"
print(person.age) #Prints 75
```

However, you could have named the `age` and `name` variables anything in the world. If you want the user to be able to later get the name or age, you should document it. There are two ways that I personally prefer to do this:

1) Make a getter method and document that. I like this because it doesn't tell the user where the variable is stored, it just gives them a way to get the value of it. Even though a determined user can still figure out where it's stored and change it, it makes it less likely that a user will change the age or name when they aren't supposed to.

2) Document the presence of the variable. This is good especially if you want the user to have full control, and be able to reset the value, or if you are trying to simplify the number of definitions in your class.

Bonus: You could also make a `def __str__(self):` that returns a string that says something like

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name + " is " + str(self.age) + " years old."
```

So that a person only has to `print` your object and they can see all the info, and document that. That way, the user doesn't have to be concerned with accessing attributes or methods of the object.

Comment: Yes, I document all the __init__ arguments. So I should make all the __init__ arguments as attributes? And for read-only attributes, do I document it as read-only or have the user of the class understand they can't change it once set via when they try to modify it but the @property decorator doesn't let them?

Comment: In python, if a user is determined enough to change a value, even a read-only one, it can be very difficult to stop them. It's better to document it and say it is read only, then give them getter methods to use that way they can get at the information easily, and then hope they aren't too overly determined to mess with the object's attributes.